# Getting the correct format of the datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, backend

I have a column inside of my datebase that stores a date that user pick when they offer a job. It's currently formed in this way: "Fri Feb 15 2019".

I want to be able to compare it to the current date which is formed as: "2019-01-27"

I'm guessing that the best way to do this would be to transform the datepicker format to the date one, and then compare them. This is the code that I have for the date picker currently when someone registeres.

```
<div class="form-group">                                             
<label for="location" class="control-label">DATE</label>                                                         
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick a 
date" name="datepicker">                                             
</div>
```

```
   <script>
    var picker = new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementById('datepicker') }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, does your date picker actually *submit* the value in that format? Because the built-in `<input type="date" />` (which you **should** use) displays it in a locale-specific format but will always submit `Y-m-d` format.

Comment: with vanilla javascript check the example below hope you get what you want or you can explain clearly with a better example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the example in full page :

Use `new Date` and then you can extract the `day` the `month` and the `year`

and to compare with another date, you can just `new Date("2006-05-1").getMonth() === new Date("2006-05-2").getMonth() &&` ...

```js
var picker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('datepicker')
});


const dateInput = document.getElementById('datepicker');

function handleChange() {
  const date = new Date(dateInput.value),
    formattedDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}`;
  console.log(formattedDate)
}

dateInput.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/css/pikaday.css">
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the javascript plugin called Momentjs. It allows for easy formatting of dates, without the base javascript hassle.

Add this to your HTML, near the bottom of your page, but before your script tags:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Then to format your datepicker value, inside your script, use:

```
var myDate = moment(picker.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Here is the Momentjs documentation:
[Momentjs Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)